# Unable to do XSLT transformation on a latin2 xml document

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xpath

I want to run a XSLT conversion on a xml document which is in latin-2 encoding
The xml doc looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-2"?>
<Cégjegyzék>
  <Kiadmány>
    <CégAdatlap>...</CégAdatlap>
    <CégAdatlap>...</CégAdatlap>
    <CégAdatlap>...</CégAdatlap>
  </Kiadmány>
</Cégjegyzék>
```

My XSLT tries to iterate through those elements.

```
<results>
            <xsl:for-each select="//Cégjegyzék/Kiadmány/CégAdatlap" >
                     ...
            </xsl:for-each>
</results>
```

However the output will always look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><results/>
```

I am thinking that the XPath doesn't work due to encoding issues, that's why I tried to convert to utf8 like this

```
byte[] latin2 = xml.getBytes("ISO-8859-2");
byte[] utf8 = new String(latin2, "ISO-8859-2").getBytes("UTF-8");
String utf8String = new String(utf8);
utf8String = utf8String.replace("ISO-8859-2","UTF-8");
return utf8String;
```

Unfortunately this didn't help.

Anyone has a clue what the issue is and how I could fix it?

The code to initiate the tranformation:

```
TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
File f = new File(searchProviderXslt.getXsltFilename());

StreamSource ss = new StreamSource(f);
Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer(ss);

//String response = convert_response((String) resp, sc);
String response = (String) resp;
Source xml = new StreamSource((new StringReader(response)));
StreamResult xmlres = new StreamResult(new StringWriter());

transformer.transform(xml, xmlres);
String xmls = xmlres.getWriter().toString();
```

Comment: http://xsltransform.net/bFWR5Ep seems to output the three dots for each element in the input so the problem is with the rest of the code you have not shown, like a minimal but complete XSLT and of course the Java code running the transformation.

Comment: ok interesting, thanks!

Comment: I would remove all of that “conversion” code.  A Java String is always UTF-16 encoded.  Converting it to bytes and back to a String, especially without a charset (which is what `new String(utf8)` is doing), is likely to corrupt the characters and make things worse.

Comment: Sadly that doesn't work. I've added the code which initiates the conversion

Comment: @MartinHonnen I've added the code to do initiate the conversion. Could you check if you did anything differently?

Comment: Do you get that XML input as a string? Or do you have a file or stream to feed to the transformer (which will feed it to the XML parser)? But if you have a string as shown then I can't explain the error and would rather guess that the input and/or stylesheet used are not as currently shown when you get no parsing error, no transformation error but then the output `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><results/>`. The usual problem to look at first is namespaces, does the XML have an `xmlns="..."` on some elements?

Comment: @MartinHonnen As a matter of fact they do have xmlns on the root element. Thanks for that input, gonna check if that is causing the issue.

Answer (score 2):

The most obvious explanation is that the encoding of the XSLT stylesheet is incorrect. It shouldn't matter what the actual encoding is, so long as it is correctly declared. If the actual encoding of the stylesheet is iso-8859-2, but the XML declaration is omitted or says utf-8, then those names are going to be misinterpreted and won't match the names in your source document.